# LD_LIBRARY_PATH with GDB on Xeon Phi

Tags: c, gdb, gdbserver, xeon-phi

I am currently trying to debug a native application for the Xeon Phi using the GDB version provided by Intel (gdb-mic). When I run the program while logged in onto the Phi, it works provided I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp (where I previously transferred libiomp5.so).

However, when I debug the application using GDB, I am unable to set the library path. I tried the command "set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp", but GDB still can't find libiomp5.so.

Has anyone encountered that issue before ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to make it work. If I include the command to set the library path in the command to start gdbserver, such as :

target extended-remote | ssh mic0 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp /tmp/gdbserver --multi -

It manages to find the library.

Answer (score 0):

> gdb> set environment LD_PRELOAD='The LD path'

And, to resolve the .so symbols [look here](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_solib-search-path).

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not seem to find the library that way.

Comment: You forgot to mention you're debugging remotely (-;